# Postgres saves data slower than Hibernate reading the value

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, gwt

I have a GWT application which uses hibernate to connect to the postgres DB. When I run the application in tomcat on a faster server I noted a problem.

A view in my application loads old data from the db. So what happend? In a view, the user can enter some data and then he hits the save button. This causes a async call in which I save the data through hibernate to postgres. As soon as I do a commit() in the code (I set lazy update to false), I get back from the async call and then I do a refresh of the view (=reload data from db and display it). This leads to a reread of the data from db. However, the view sometimes displays old data. Then I refresh the view again and I can see the correct current data.

My guess is that the commit() function of hibernate causes a async call and therefore I come back earlier from the first async call (when user hits the save button) than hibernate saving the data to postgres. Therefore the view loads old data.

Does anyone have similar problems with hibernate and postgres?

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate's 2nd level cache doesn't capture updates to the database that happen to the base entities via views, native queries, etc. I'd say you're being bitten by this, and need to either explicitly invalidate the cache when you know you've distrupted it, or need to disable it.

Another possibility is that you're working in SERIALIZABLE transaction isolation mode with a connection that has an old transaction open on it. Say your app is getting a connection from the connection pool or another part of your app and that connection already has an open transaction from before you wrote the data you're now trying to read. If that's the case, you'll see an old snapshot. This *shouldn't* happen, but buggy apps can return connections with open transactions to the pool and the pool may not be set to automatically close and reset them, or you might not be using a proper connection pool.

Of the two, I'd say Hibernate caching issues are the more likely culprit.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your thoughts. May I ask you where I need to disable the cache? Is that a general configuration or can it also be managed per table?

Comment: @mkn: See "Second level cache" in the Hibernate docs. You set it at the persistence unit level via a property. Exactly how varies version by version and by how you're using Hibernate - directly or via JPA's persistence.xml.

If disabling the 2nd level cache fixes your issue you shouldn't necessarily leave it that. Find out which query or queries are bypassing the cache and see if you can flush it or invalidate some of it after those queries run, so you get the benefit of it the rest of the time.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?

Comment: After playing around in the properties of hibernate, I stopped the reloading of the view after a save. This solved the problem so far. Disabling the cache does not seem to be a proper solution :). Thank you very much for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation is incorrect. A commit of the hibernate transaction does write and commit to the database, and if the commit succeeds, then the data is committed in the database.

What you're seeing comes from somewhere else: the browser cache, or the second-level cache if configured incorrectly (in read-only mode for example).

Another explanation would be that the second async call doesn't wait for the first one to complete before being sent to the server.

Comment: the first async call finishes when the call commit() is being finished. However, if the function commit() is being executed in another thread then that might cause the problem. The browser can't cache the data because every time I explicitly load the data from the db.

Comment: The commit is not asynchronous. If it was, it wouldn't be called a transaction anymore.